# Pandas create series using conditional

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the titanic dataset and have a created a series Famsize. I'd like to create a second series that outputs 'single' if famsize =1, 'small' if 1 < famsize < 5 and 'large' if famsize >=5.

```
   Famsize FamsizeDisc
     1         single
     2         small
     5         large
```

I've tried using np.where but as I have three outputs I haven't been able to find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do share what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called `binning` so use `pd.cut` i.e

```
df['new'] = pd.cut(df['Famsize'],bins=[0,1,4,np.inf],labels=['single','small','large'])
```

Output:

```
   Famsize FamsizeDisc     new
0        1      single  single
1        2       small   small
2        5       large   large
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you could create a function which does the mapping:

```
def get_sizeDisc(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 'single'
    elif x < 5:
        return 'small'
    elif x >= 5:
        return 'large'

df['FamsizeDisc'] = df.Famsize.apply(get_sizeDisc)
```

Or you could use `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.Famsize==1, 'FamsizeDisc'] = 'single'
df.loc[df.Famsize.between(1,5, inclusive = False), 'FamsizeDisc'] = 'small'
df.loc[df.Famsize>=5, 'FamsizeDisc'] = 'large'
```

Comment: My bad, hadn't reloaded the page to see your answer. I'll remove it from my answer and upvote yours, as it's clearly the more concise solution :D